# What is the name of the anime kids, mecha and fantasy series with a group of 4?

Tags: story-identification, tv, anime

I am looking for an old kids, mecha, fantasy anime series which possibly aired on Toonami, Cartoon Network or a channel possibly before that.

The main cast consisted of a group of 5, with 4 of them each having specific alien-like creatures which could turn into animal-looking robots with transformation. The 4 consisted of two boys and two girls.

This is a scene I remember that displays all their characters as the antagonist alien was spying on them with a small flying robot. One of the boys (which MIGHT be the main, main character) is a total careless dude that bumped onto a pole. I forgot about the other boy. One of the girls (which I remember had a dandere-like character/impression?) was completely terrible at maths and was cooking/baking, and so I presume she was good at cooking (in fact I think she cooks for the gang). The other girl was kind of a rich type of girl (if I remember correctly), and had some martial arts training, I think she was good in fighting? I remember she even broke the flying robot that was spying on the whole gang.

The antagonist at the time was spying on all of them, and kept on asking the question: “Why would he/she have an (alien-like creature I forgot the name of)?” The fifth main character would be the younger sister of the ‘rich’ girl but she didn’t have one of those creatures until the enemy gave her one by manipulating her. In fact, I remembered, that in the main conflicts from where I remembered their characters, the antagonist mind-controlled some of the classmates in their school so they could control the antagonist’s prepared alien-like creatures.

Does anyone (probably a teen born in the 2000-2010s) know this anime?

Comment: Check Digimon cartoon. It aired at about that time. But the number of characters is off.

Answer (score -1):

Its probably tenkai knights or king of braves gaogaigar. At least that's what I believe after reading your question.